# Slick 2.0 - update two or more columns

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, slick-2.0

I know I can update two columns in Slick 2.0 with:

```
val q = for (user <- Users if user.id === id) yield (user.name, user.city)
q.update((newName, newCity))
```

But I've seen something like this working as well which is IMO much nicer syntax:

```
Users.filter(_.id === id).map(u => u.name ~ u.city).update(newName, newCity)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
value ~ is not a member of shortcut.db.Tables.profile.simple.Column
```

I have imported PostgresDriver.simple._ and I just can't figure out why. I also use the code generator.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `~` method was [moved out of the normal import scope](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/migration.html) for Slick 2.0.  You can either use a tuple, just as is:

```
Users.filter(_.id === id).map(u => (u.name, u.city)).update((newName, newCity))
```

or import the necessary [TupleMethods](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/api/#scala.slick.util.TupleMethods%24) object:

```
import scala.slick.util.TupleMethods._
Users.filter(_.id === id).map(u => u.name ~ u.city).update((newName, newCity))
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sean Vieira's answer:

`for (user <- Users if user.id === id) yield (user.name, user.city)`

is just syntactic sugar for

`Users.filter(_.id === id).map(u => (u.name, u.city))`

and that's not Slick-specific, it's the Scala compiler that desugars this for Scala-collections, for Slick, for anything.